# Getting error while trying to poll multiple accounts from database using mailman server in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailman

Hi I am trying to access multiple accounts from database using mailman server in RoR. But I'm getting the following error

```
script/mailman_server:7:in `<main>': uninitialized constant EmailConfig (NameError)
```

Here is what I tried to achieve my task:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"
require "mailman"

Mailman.config.logger = Logger.new("log/mailman.log") # uncomment this if you can want to create a log fill
@email_con = EmailConfig.find_by_sql(["SELECT email_id, password FROM email_configs"])
Mailman.config.poll_interval = 3 # change this number as per your needs. Default is 60 seconds
Mailman.config.pop3 = { server: 'pop.gmail.com', 
                        port: 995, ssl: true, 
                        username: @email_con.email_id,
                        password: @email_con.password }

**Logic starts here**
Mailman::Application.run do
default do
begin
-------
end
```

Any ideas would be grateful. Thanks